# Strange behavior when graphing a function (Maple)

Tags: limits, maple

I was doing a presentation on Limits and I was using this $$f(x)=\frac{x^2+2x-8}{x^2-4}$$ to explain different types of limits.

I know that the function is not defined at $x=-2$ or $x=2$.  I showed the graph and everyone was ok with the graph at $x=-2$ but one member of the audience didn't like how the graph looked at $x=2$.

I think they didn't understand that a function doesn't need to be defined at the point to have a limit.  I said there was a hole at $x=2$, not sure now because when I restricted the domain to be close to $x=2$ This was displayed.

[image: graph of f(x) near x=2]

I used "discont=true" as an option of the plot command.

I computed both the left and right limits of $f(x), \; x\to 2$, both limits equal 3/2. I don't think there is any up and down behavior like $\sin(1/x)$

Is this a problem with maple or have I missed something about limits?

Comment: Simplify: $$\frac{x^2+2x-8}{x^2-4} = \frac{(x^2-4) + 2(x-2)}{x^2-4} = 1 + \frac{2}{x+2}$$ is perfectly well-behaved near $2$. It's an artifact of floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: This doesn't happen to me, I get a nice, smooth curve with the generic command "plot". I use Maple 17.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, that definitely shouldn't be happening. I think it must be an error with arithmetic with very small numbers, as computers only have so much precision.  (You've used $|x-2|<10^{-7}$ so $|x^2-4|<10^{-14}$ which is the range you get problems in).

EDIT: the above is actually slightly wrong. $|x-2|<10^{-7}$ implies $|x^2-4|<4*10^{-7}$. Nonetheless, it's a problem with high precision arithmetic.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, you are seeing artefacts of floating-point computation. These can be alleviated by increasing the working precision, by adjusting the `Digits` environment variable.

The default value of `Digits` is 10. Also, for an expression containing only arithmetic operations (and elementary functions) Maple's 'plot' command will try to use its faster `evalhf` double-precision interpreter if Digits is less than 15 which is `trunc(evalhf(Digits))`.

For your example the `plot` command's option `discont=[showremovable]` will mark the plot of the expression f at x=2 with a symbol. This works for your f which is an explicit expression, for which Maple uses its symbolic `discont` procedure to find the point discontinuity. It may not work if f were instead an operator (procedure), since in that case Maple would fall back to using its purely numeric `fdiscont` procedure.

```
restart:
f := (x^2+2*x-8)/(x^2-4):

Digits := 20: # increased working precision -- default is 10

plot( f, x=2-1e-6 .. 2+1e-6, discont=[showremovable] );
```

[image]

Using a wider domain the plotting command does not compute enough evaluations near x=2 to produce the artefacts you saw.

```
Digits := 10: # the default

plot( f, x=-3..3, discont=[showremovable] );
```

[image]